# Trying to compile a simple file in C

Tags: c, file, gcc, compilation, header

I am writing you because I wrote the following file sources in C and I am not able to compile it with gcc... I get the error unknow type name :(
I searched on the internet but in most of cases it appears when there is a circular dependency or something like that.

So I have a source file and a header file :

vector.h :

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct dynamic_array_struct
{
    uint64_t *data;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
} vector;

int
vector_init(vector *, size_t);

int
vector_reinit(vector *);

#endif /* VECTOR_H */
```

and vector.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector.h>


int
vector_init(vector *v, size_t init_capacity)
{
    v->data = (uint64_t *)malloc(init_capacity*sizeof(uint64_t));
    v->capacity = init_capacity;
    v->size = 0;
    return 1;
}

int
vector_reinit(vector *v)
{
    free(v->data);
    v->data = (uint64_t *)malloc(v->capacity*sizeof(uint64_t));
    v->size = 0;
    return 1;
}
```

But when I try to compile it with `gcc -c vector.c -I .` I get the following error :

```
In file included from vector.c:2:0:
./vector.h:2:13: error: unknown type name ‘vector’
 vector_init(vector *, size_t);
             ^
./vector.h:5:15: error: unknown type name ‘vector’
 vector_reinit(vector *);
               ^
vector.c:6:13: error: unknown type name ‘vector’
 vector_init(vector *v, size_t init_capacity)
             ^
vector.c:14:15: error: unknown type name ‘vector’
 vector_reinit(vector *v)
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I thought I did with my typedef struct ... vector; in the top of my header file, no ?

Comment: Should be `#include "vector.h"` in your .c file, but doesn't really matter here. Can't reproduce your problem either, compiles fine. (You're missing `<stdint.h>` too for int64_t.)

Comment: @Raoul722 Are you sure, these are only error message, nothing missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include vector.h like this:

```
#include "vector.h"
```

not like this:

```
#include <vector.h>
```

Comment: So you're assuming there's two vector.h ? If not compiler should have thrown an error

Comment: I can not see any other problem with what Raoul722 has posted. Personal libraries should be in quotes, not angle brackets.